# Exact replacement in a file

Tags: unix

I have data as:

```
abc aabcd abcd Abc
ABCjj abcdef abc abcGHI abc
```

I want it as:

PQR replaces abc:
output:

```
PQR aabcd abcd Abc
ABCjj abcdef PQR abcGHI PQR
```

Here only exact **abc** are replaced wit **PQR**,   and    **abcdef,abcGHI are as they were**.

Comment: The exact string `abc` appears as a substring of `abcdef`.  Perhaps you mean something other than "exact abc". (eg, word boundaries)

Answer (score 2):

```
printf ',s/\<abc\>/PQR/g;w;' | tr \; \\012 | ed input-file
```

You can also write this (perhaps more readably) as:

```
ed input-file << EOF
,s/\<abc\>/PQR/g
w
EOF
```